# how to search everywhere within a specific directory (including sub folders) using python

Tags: python-3.x

basically, as the title says, I want to be able to use a python script where I give a path/directory, and a file name, and it will search all the way through the path/directory just to find the file name.

I have tried using `glob.glob()` however it will only search within the directory and not within subfolders and such from what I have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`glob.glob()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) (emphasis mine), starting at Python 3.5:

> If `recursive` is true, the pattern `"**"` will match any files and zero or more directories, **subdirectories** and symbolic links to directories.

So you just put `**` into your pattern where you want it to expand to any subdirectories and files therein and add `recursive=True` as a keyword argument.

For example, given a directory structure like

```
a
+-b
| +-d
|   +-f
+-c
  +-e
```

with your current working directory being `a`, you can do:

```py
>>> from glob import glob
>>> glob("**", recursive=True)
['c', 'c/e', 'b', 'b/d', 'b/d/f']
```

For your specific use case of searching for a filename in all subdirectories, you'd do:

```py
>>> glob("**/f", recursive=True)
['b/d/f']
```

Note that `**` patterns also work in [`pathlib.Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) and `pathlib` paths are often more comfortable to use than the more low-level `os.path` and `glob` modules.